# How do I incorporate spacing into recursive?

Tags: python

```
def PrintDT(Tennis):
    print "Split on Tennis[0]"
    for a in Tennis[1]:
        print "If tennis[0] == a " 
        if isinstance(Tennis[1][a], str):
            PrintDT(tennis)
        else:       
            print "Return:>>>5*' 'Tennis[1][a]"
```

So the formatting that I am supposed to achieve is :

```
Split on  Outlook
 If Outlook == Sunny
      Split on  Humidity
      If Humidity == High
           Return:  No
      If Humidity == Low
           Return:    Yes
 If Outlook == Overcast
      Return:    Yes
 If Outlook == Rain
      Split on  Wind
      If Wind == Strong
           Return:   No
      If Wind == Weak
           Return:    Yes
```

I think that I have the recursive program down, but know I need to do the correct formatting. PLease HELP

Comment: So the question is, how do you `print` multiple spaces?

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the variable names out of the string literals you are printing. Currently, you're just printing a bunch of strings that won't change, but if you remove the variable names from the `"`s, you should fine. It would be helpful if we knew what `Tennis` was, but this should at least get you closer to the right answer.

```
def PrintDT(Tennis):
    print "Split on", Tennis[0]
    for a in Tennis[1]:
        print "If", tennis[0], "==", a
        if isinstance(Tennis[1][a], str):
            PrintDT(tennis)
        else:
            print "Return:     " + Tennis[1][a]
```